# Android AutoCompleteTextView, how to seperate query key and value (label)

Tags: android, autocomplete

I want to build an AutoCompleteTextView to filter on my big list. The list have two attributes, one is short representation of the list item , and another one is the full style of the item, for example, one item named "DoYouKnow", and its short style may be "dyk".

When user type "dy" or "doy", it would both match the item "DoYouKnow", and the AutoCompleteTextView should show "DoYouKnow" up, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i get it done by implementing my own filter in adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using hashmap with key and value